# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 Error Android

Tags: android

Could you please tell me why am I getting this error? What I did wrong?

```
int[] songPos = {R.raw.position1,R.raw.position2,R.raw.position3,R.raw.position4};
    UnitPackage=getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+songPos[position], null, UnitPackage);
                   MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(CentralActivity.this, resId);  

                   if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.pause();
                    } else {
                        mp.start();
                    }
               }
               });

    07-11 10:06:26.051: W/ResourceType(21457): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    07-11 10:06:26.051: D/AndroidRuntime(21457): Shutting down VM
    07-11 10:06:26.051: W/dalvikvm(21457): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418268b0)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1125)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1083)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:837)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at goldenRing.rootapp.com.CentralActivity$1.onItemClick(CentralActivity.java:75)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1104)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2792)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3468)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    07-11 10:06:26.071: E/AndroidRuntime(21457):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Metho

d)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something or? Do I need to find another way for this or it can be solved?

Comment: What is `UnitPackage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+songPos[position], null, UnitPackage);
```

to

```
int resId = songPos[position];
```

You have already stored all the `id` in the `songPos`. No need to retrieve it again using `getIdentifier`